# I am unable to access and make some operation in 3D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

`df` is a `3D` array mentioned below and which consists of 3 2D array and I should access last column of `2D` array along all rows.

```
array([[[4.3, 3.0, 1.1, 0.1, 'Setosa'],
        [4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.4, 3.0, 1.3, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.5, 2.3, 1.3, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [4.6, 3.6, 1.0, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.1, 'Setosa'],
        [4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [4.8, 3.4, 1.9, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.8, 3.1, 1.6, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.9, 2.4, 3.3, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [4.9, 2.5, 4.5, 1.7, 'Virginica'],
        [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1, 'Setosa'],
        [4.9, 3.6, 1.4, 0.1, 'Setosa'],
        [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 3.5, 1.3, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 3.4, 1.6, 0.4, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 3.3, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 3.2, 1.2, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 3.5, 1.6, 0.6, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 2.0, 3.5, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 2.3, 3.3, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.0, 3.0, 1.6, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.8, 1.9, 0.4, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.8, 1.6, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 2.5, 3.0, 1.1, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4, 'Setosa'],
        [5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [5.2, 4.1, 1.5, 0.1, 'Setosa'],
        [5.2, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.2, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.2, 2.7, 3.9, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.3, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.4, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 'Setosa'],
        [5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.4, 3.4, 1.5, 0.4, 'Setosa']],

       [[5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4, 'Setosa'],
        [5.5, 3.5, 1.3, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.5, 2.6, 4.4, 1.2, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.5, 4.2, 1.4, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.5, 2.3, 4.0, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.5, 2.4, 3.7, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.5, 2.4, 3.8, 1.1, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.5, 2.5, 4.0, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.6, 3.0, 4.1, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.6, 2.8, 4.9, 2.0, 'Virginica'],
        [5.6, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.6, 2.5, 3.9, 1.1, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.6, 2.7, 4.2, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.6, 2.9, 3.6, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.7, 2.6, 3.5, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.7, 2.9, 4.2, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.7, 2.8, 4.1, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4, 'Setosa'],
        [5.7, 2.8, 4.5, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.7, 2.5, 5.0, 2.0, 'Virginica'],
        [5.7, 3.8, 1.7, 0.3, 'Setosa'],
        [5.7, 3.0, 4.2, 1.2, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.8, 2.7, 4.1, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.8, 4.0, 1.2, 0.2, 'Setosa'],
        [5.8, 2.6, 4.0, 1.2, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.8, 2.8, 5.1, 2.4, 'Virginica'],
        [5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9, 'Virginica'],
        [5.8, 2.7, 3.9, 1.2, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9, 'Virginica'],
        [5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [5.9, 3.0, 4.2, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [5.9, 3.2, 4.8, 1.8, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.0, 2.9, 4.5, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.0, 2.7, 5.1, 1.6, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.0, 3.0, 4.8, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.0, 3.4, 4.5, 1.6, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.0, 2.2, 4.0, 1.0, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.0, 2.2, 5.0, 1.5, 'Virginica'],
        [6.1, 3.0, 4.9, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.1, 2.6, 5.6, 1.4, 'Virginica'],
        [6.1, 2.8, 4.0, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.1, 2.9, 4.7, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.1, 2.8, 4.7, 1.2, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.1, 3.0, 4.6, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.2, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [6.2, 2.8, 4.8, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.3, 2.5, 4.9, 1.5, 'Versicolor']],

       [[6.3, 2.7, 4.9, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.3, 2.5, 5.0, 1.9, 'Virginica'],
        [6.3, 3.3, 4.7, 1.6, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.3, 2.8, 5.1, 1.5, 'Virginica'],
        [6.3, 3.3, 6.0, 2.5, 'Virginica'],
        [6.3, 2.3, 4.4, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.3, 3.4, 5.6, 2.4, 'Virginica'],
        [6.3, 2.9, 5.6, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.2, 'Virginica'],
        [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1, 'Virginica'],
        [6.4, 3.1, 5.5, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.4, 3.2, 5.3, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [6.4, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.4, 2.7, 5.3, 1.9, 'Virginica'],
        [6.5, 3.0, 5.8, 2.2, 'Virginica'],
        [6.5, 3.0, 5.5, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.5, 3.0, 5.2, 2.0, 'Virginica'],
        [6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.5, 3.2, 5.1, 2.0, 'Virginica'],
        [6.6, 2.9, 4.6, 1.3, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.6, 3.0, 4.4, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.7, 3.1, 4.7, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.7, 3.1, 5.6, 2.4, 'Virginica'],
        [6.7, 2.5, 5.8, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [6.7, 3.0, 5.0, 1.7, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.7, 3.1, 4.4, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.5, 'Virginica'],
        [6.7, 3.0, 5.2, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.1, 'Virginica'],
        [6.8, 3.2, 5.9, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [6.8, 2.8, 4.8, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.8, 3.0, 5.5, 2.1, 'Virginica'],
        [6.9, 3.1, 5.4, 2.1, 'Virginica'],
        [6.9, 3.1, 5.1, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [6.9, 3.1, 4.9, 1.5, 'Versicolor'],
        [6.9, 3.2, 5.7, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [7.0, 3.2, 4.7, 1.4, 'Versicolor'],
        [7.1, 3.0, 5.9, 2.1, 'Virginica'],
        [7.2, 3.0, 5.8, 1.6, 'Virginica'],
        [7.2, 3.2, 6.0, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [7.2, 3.6, 6.1, 2.5, 'Virginica'],
        [7.3, 2.9, 6.3, 1.8, 'Virginica'],
        [7.4, 2.8, 6.1, 1.9, 'Virginica'],
        [7.6, 3.0, 6.6, 2.1, 'Virginica'],
        [7.7, 2.8, 6.7, 2.0, 'Virginica'],
        [7.7, 2.6, 6.9, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [7.7, 3.8, 6.7, 2.2, 'Virginica'],
        [7.7, 3.0, 6.1, 2.3, 'Virginica'],
        [7.9, 3.8, 6.4, 2.0, 'Virginica']]], dtype=object)
```

I tried:

```py
  element = df[g_index[[i],[4]]]
```

but it returns an error

```py
def Numberofoccurences(data,sortcolindex,g_index):
    df =  DivideColumns(data,sortcolindex)
    num_Iris_setosa = 0
    num_Iris_versicolor = 0
    num_Iris_virginica = 0
    for i in range(0,50):
           element = df[g_index[[i],[4]]]
           if(element == 'Setosa'):
               num_Iris_setosa+=1
           elif(element == 'Versicolor'):
               num_Iris_versicolor+=1
           elif (element == 'Virginica'):
               num_Iris_virginica+=1
    array1D_for_occ = np.array([num_Iris_virginica,num_Iris_versicolor,num_Iris_setosa])
    return array1D_for_occ ;


numberofocc = Numberofoccurences(iris_array,0,0)
```

The error I get is

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: please give us sample data and values of sortcolindex and g_index. thanks.

Comment: see the post again, thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of DivideColumns?

Comment: you call `Numberofoccurences(iris_array,0,0)` with last zero, but in function expecting  multi-dim list `g_index[[i],[4]]` which *s not subscriptable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Not subscriptable' means you cannot index into it. So `g_index[i]` is not allowed.

Maybe you want:

```
element = df[g_index, i, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix on your function.  So you do a loop on each element in data[g_index] and to get the last element, you put each[-1] where -1 means last element of the list.

```
def Numberofoccurences(data,sortcolindex,g_index):
    df =  DivideColumns(data,sortcolindex)
    num_Iris_setosa = 0
    num_Iris_versicolor = 0
    num_Iris_virginica = 0
    for each in df[g_index]:
        element = each[-1]
        if(element == 'Setosa'):
            num_Iris_setosa+=1
        elif(element == 'Versicolor'):
            num_Iris_versicolor+=1
        elif (element == 'Virginica'):
            num_Iris_virginica+=1
    array1D_for_occ = np.array([num_Iris_virginica,num_Iris_versicolor,num_Iris_setosa])
    return array1D_for_occ
```